# I want to swipe to find/locate an element that is present down in an IOS App

Tags: java, eclipse, appium, xcuitest

I have an Ios app and I'm doing UI automation of it. I have an element/button that is one scroll down the page. I have seen that appium has depreciated most of the functions like scroll, moveto and swipe. since all of the help is related to that. I am using Appium Version 1.13.0 (1.13.0.20190505.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that method instead of appium methods:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
js.executeScript("mobile: swipe", scrollObject);
```

change `direction` to up if you want to swipe up

Comment: How is it not working? has it failed with exception or what?

Comment: It doesn't scroll down.

Comment: since I'm trying to find an element after scrolling down a bit. So as it doesn't scroll down it gives no element found exception

Comment: try this method with js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject); can you ensure that scroll is working? (take a look at the screen)